# multiple form data with same name

Tags: php, html

I have a html form multiple data with same name. like this...

HTML code

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="asset_id" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="batch_code" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="description" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="asset_id" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="batch_code" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="description" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
```

how to send this in php $_POST[] to back-end process. please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="asset_id[]" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="batch_code[]" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="description[]" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="asset_id[]" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="batch_code[]" size="15"/></td>
  <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="description[]" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
```

Note that there's no `type="textbox"`; the correct `type` is `text`.
In PHP, access the data like this:

```
$_POST["asset_id"]; // this is an array of the values of the asset_id textboxes
$_POST["batch_code"]; // array of batch codes
$_POST["description"]; // array of descriptions
```

Answer (score 5):

Append `Square Bracket []` to your names:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="asset_id[]" size="15"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="batch_code[]" size="15"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="text" name="description[]" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="asset_id[]" size="15"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="batch_code[]" size="15"/></td>
    <td valign="top"><input id="" type="textbox" name="description[]" size="50"/></td>
</tr>
```

in your php:

```
<?php
    print_r( $_POST['asset_id'] );
    print_r( $_POST['batch_code'] );
    print_r( $_POST['description'] );
?>
```